# Run SSRS on Chrome

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I know that this question is asked zillion of times, but none of the solutions helped me.

I've followed this instructions:

http://www.macaalay.com/2014/01/23/show-ssrs-reports-properly-in-chrome-and-safari/

I can see `rdl` files, and can run them in `Chrome,` but result is not visible. When I set `OverFlow` to `Visible` in Chrome HTML (`F12`), report results magically appear.

When I try to append code part to `js` file in `SSRS` server, nothing changes (Chrome still doesn't show up).

Report runs correctly in IE, I've even restarted service and I'm using correct ctl id

What am I doing wrong according to that article?

Comment: You should use the F12 tools as explained in that link to verify that the overflow is set to visible

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I did this, I did every step in article. When I manually change HTML by F12 to visible that works. But I can't ask everybody to change it manually each time they run report :)

Comment: Did you make the change to the `ReportingServices.js` file as mentioned in the article? If you did, then that is what needs to be troubleshooted

Comment: You need to use F12 tools to confirm that your `.js` file change has stuck, and no errors occurred. Are there any errors in the console in the F12 tools?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I have changed .js file, but nothing changes. After changing js, HTML in F12 doesn't change at all, no errors. Maybe I should deploy somehow that js file? I just appended that script part and saved.

Comment: In chrome, press F12, go to the sources tab, then go to the sources sub tab then go to the scripts folder, open it out, find `ReportingServices.js` and confirm that is has the change that you applied. If not press CTRL-F5 to force a full refresh and clear your cache as the old `.js` file might be cached

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, +100 for Ctrl+F5, didn't know that, refreshed, and that worked. Please, post answer, so that I can accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have edited your `ReportingServices.js` file but no change is observed, it might be that the old `.js` file is cached. Press <kbd>CTRL-F5</kbd> to force a full refresh.

You can also observe the `.js` file actually being used as per my earlier comments

Comment: Also this might assist in forcing the js file to be stale and therefore automatically uploaded to all clients without requiring CTRL-F5: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ForcingAnUpdateOfACachedJavaScriptFileInIIS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below extension for chrome browser then it will work perfectly no need to change your JS and HTML code:

[SSRS Report Display Problem On Chrome Browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-report-fix/fjbdfjiheheafbioiejbdpalmojkeobk/related)

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your Chrome browser's setting page --> Extensions --> Get more extensions, then search for "SSRS". You'll find several SSRS Fix. Try and see which one works for your machine.